# xcode 9 quits unexpectedly when changing textures in gamescene.sks

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

I'm trying to create a game in xcode 9 using gamescene.sks file by adding a couple of color sprite nodes. However when I try to change the texture of any of my color sprite nodes Xcode quits unexpectedly (I crashes).

(By the I'm using the right size images and the right format. I even have the latest Macbook pro.)

(this is the top part of the problem report of xcode, its so long that I can't paste it on the question board)

```
Process:               Xcode [1843]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               9.2 (13772)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-13772000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       825038102
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1843]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-02-01 15:20:41.066 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.3 (17D47)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        EA3AEA4A-6BD5-57A3-7755-0303E965D63E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       B044A2BB-7551-4801-A7F9-3F3557857C19

Time Awake Since Boot: 13000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       5100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Sending userDidChangeValue: to <SKInspectorTextureProperty: 0x7fd6c98e4b50> from <NSComboBox: 0x7fd6c98e7480>
ProductBuildVersion: 9C40b
Performing @selector(userDidChangeValue:) from sender NSComboBox 0x7fd6c98e7480
abort() called
*** error for object 0x7fd6c73a3200: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

**Does anyone know a way around this problem?**

**Is anyone getting the same error and have a solution?**

**I already tried this workaround that was attached to another user question but it doesn't work.**

*There is a great workaround on the Apple forums.*

*How to fix your .sks file :*

- *Open your .sks file outside the project (close your project and open the file directly from Finder)*
- *You should see red crosses instead of the Sprites, delete the Texture name information for all of them.*
- *Now, you should be able to reopen the file from the project.*
- *Finally, reenter the Texture name for all your Sprites.*